# How to verify strings and doubles in switch satements

Tags: c

I'm new to programming its just been like a week.
I was trying to solve a question of school homework using switch statements in c programming language. But i'm unable to verify entered strings or doubles using switch statements.

Following is my question:

> Q3. A company decides to give bonus to all its employees on New Year. It is decided that 5% bonus will be given to all male employees and 10% bonus will be given to female employees. Further, if the salary of an employee is less than Rs. 10,000, then the employee gets an extra 2% bonus on salary. Write a C program switch…case construct to enter the salary and gender of an employee and calculate the bonus that has to be given to an employee.

Following is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char gender[6];
    double salary;
    double bonusSalary;

    printf("enter your gender here:");
    scanf("%s", gender);
    printf("enter your salary here:");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);

    switch(gender && salary)
    {
    case "male" && salary<10000 :
        bonusSalary=salary*(7.0/100.0);
        break;
    case "male" :
        bonusSalary=salary*(5.0/100.0);
        break;
    case "female" && salary<10000 :
        bonusSalary=salary*(10.0/100.0);
        break;
    case "female" :
        bonusSalary=salary*(12.0/100.0);
        break;
    default :
        printf("invalid input");
        break;

        }
        printf("your bonus salary is:%f", bonusSalary);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting errors as:
"case label does reduce to integer constant" for all the case statements I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly stated by @ElKurshum, you cannot use strings in `switch` statements. But, you can use `int`, `char`, `short`, `long`, etc. Please find the below modified code using `switch` statements. Do read the comments to understand the changes done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char gender;
    double salary;
    double bonusSalary;
    
    int gender_code;
    
    printf("enter your gender here [M/F]: ");
    scanf("%c", &gender);
    
    printf("enter your salary here: ");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);
    
    // salary_lt_10000 will be either 0 or 1
    int salary_lt_10000 = salary < 10000.0;
    
    // Mapping used:
    // M -> 100
    // F -> 200
    // M with salary < 10000 -> 101
    // F with salary < 10000 -> 201
    switch (gender)
    {
        case 'M':
            // Input is ok
            gender_code = 100 + salary_lt_10000;
            break;
        case 'F':
            // Input is ok
            gender_code = 200 + salary_lt_10000;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid input. Expected 'M' or 'F'\n");
            return 1;
    }
    
    // printf("gender_code = %d\n", gender_code);

    // No need to divide the values for percentage,
    // for example, we know 5/100 is always 0.05 and so on for other values.
    switch (gender_code)
    {
        case 100:
            bonusSalary = 0.05 * salary;
            break;
        case 101:
            bonusSalary = 0.07 * salary;
            break;
        case 200:
            bonusSalary = 0.10 * salary;
            break;
        case 201:
            bonusSalary = 0.12 * salary;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Something went wrong...\n");
            return 1;
    }
    
    printf("your bonus salary is: %lf\n", bonusSalary);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` doesn’t work like that.  The controlling expression must be an integer expression (which `gender && salary < 10000` is, as I’ll explain below) and the `case` labels must be integer constant expressions like `65` or `'A'` or similar.  You can’t switch on strings or floating point values.

`gender` is an array expression; in this context it "decays" to a pointer expression and its value is the address of the first element of the array.  Because of how you’ve declared it, this will always be non-zero.  `salary < 10000` will evaluate to `1` if true and `0` if false.

The result of an `&&` expression is `1` if both operands are non-zero, `0` otherwise.  The left operand is fully evaluated (and any side effects applied) - if the result is non-zero, then the right-hand side is evaluated.  If the left operand is `0`, then the right operand isn’t evaluated at all.

So if that’s your controlling expression, the only cases you have are `0` and `1`, which don’t capture all the possible combinations of inputs.

For what you are trying to do a `switch` statement is not appropriate - you should use an `if-else` statement instead:

```
#include <string.h>
...
if ( strcmp( gender, "male" ) == 0 )
{
  if ( salary < 10000 )
  {
    bonusSalary = salary * 0.07;
  }
  else
  {
    bonusSalary = salary * 0.05:
  }
}
else if ( strcmp( gender, ”female" ) == 0 )
{
  // compute bonus for female
}
else
{
  // unrecognized gender entry, handle as appropriate
}
```

The `==` operator is not defined for strings, so you have to use `strcmp` for string comparisons (returns `0` is the strings are identical, non-zero otherwise).  Note `strcmp` is case-sensitive.

Finally, when you declare an array to store strings, you must set aside at least one more element than the maximum string length to account for the string terminator - that means your `gender` array needs be to 7 elements wide, not 6.  The string `"female"` is represented as the sequence `{'f', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'l', 'e', 0}`, which is 7 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only int, char or enum to a switch statement. Other types are not allowed. So if you want to compare strings and floats you should use strcmp() in string.h for the string comparison and create yourself a function for comparing the floats.